# Как перейти на новую версию C++?

Tags: c++

Сейчас версия языка 201402. Как перейти на C++17/20? Сижу на Linux.

Comment: установить, не?

Comment: Посоветуйте команду, которую можно ввести в терминале

Comment: Версия языка 201402, что это ?

Comment: Это значит стандарт языка C++14, версия 201402, проверяется через std::cout << __cplusplus;

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего на линуксе компилятор gcc или clang, то просто добавьте в командную строку `-std=c++17` для 17 стандарта. Для 20 стандарта нужно использовать соответственно `-std=c++20` или `-std=c++2a`, если компилятор чуточку старый.

Список поддерживаемых стандартов в зависимости от версии компилятора для [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

Версию компилятора можно узнать с помощью параметра командной строки `--version`

Comment: Cпасибо, а по умолчанию как нибудь можно установить? Или обязательно писать стандарт перед компиляцией?

Comment: Просто VS code ругается на новые возможности С++17, и кругом показывает ошибки, что такого нет

Comment: Выставить можно, но обычно это решается в сборочных скриптах. Если редактор ругается - нужно посмотреть, где у него можно поправить настройки.

Comment: @Rumeone Файл `c_cpp_properties.json` в проекте есть?

Comment: Нет, а для чего он нужен?

Comment: VS Code, если компилировать с std=c++17, все в порядке. Просто из за этого нет автоподстановки функций содержащих string_view, обращения к ним(именно в редакторе, компилируется все хорошо)

Comment: @Rumeone Попробуйте так: Откройте свой проект в VS Code. Нажмите `Ctrl + Shift + P`. В строке поиска пишем `C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)` и выбираем этот пункт. Откроется вкладка, в которой, если поискать, есть пункт `C++ Standart` и рядом выпадающий список с разными стандартами. Выбирайте какой нужно и просто закройте эту вкладку.

Comment: @Rumeone А вообще на сайте VS Code есть очень подробный туториал по настройке. Вот ссылка: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux